# Here maps custom marker with custom 'center'

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am adding custom markers to a Here V3 map, but by default, it is the top-left pixel that is attached to the marker's cooredinates that I am trying to pin-point.

[image: The pin]

Is there a way that I could tell the DomMarker the precise pixel that correlates to the required position?

```
var outerElement = document.createElement('div'),
innerElement = document.createElement('div');

innerElement.innerHTML = '<img src="/Images/' + getMarkerImage(donation) + '" />';
outerElement.appendChild(innerElement);

var domIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(outerElement, {});
var domMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(
    { lat: donation.Lat, lng: donation.Long },
    { icon: domIconn}
);

map.addObject(domMarker);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure its best-practice, but this seems to work...

```
innerElement.innerHTML = '<img src="/Images/' + getMarkerImage(donation) + '" style="margin-left:-28px; margin-top:-34px;" />';
```

Comment: Seems like the proper solution to me. Maybe -50%, -100%? Should work with different image sizes then, no?

Comment: So long as the pointer 'dot' is in the same relative location.  The V2 documentation shows that it used to be possible, which is why all this feels a little hacky

Comment: Just looked at the example on developer.here.com. They do exactly the same thing in their DOM Marker example (http://developer.here.com/aeapp/data/template-web-default/examples/create-dom-marker/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest JavaScript SDK from Here Maps, you can set a position for your custom marker through the [anchor](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.0.3/dev_guide/topics_api/h-map-icon-options.html#h-map-icon-options__anchor) property(by default the position is set to `bottom-center`).

Let's suppose the size of your custom icon is `markerWidth x markerHeight` and you're looking to center it. Then you'll need to create the marker sending the `H.map.Icon.Options` property when you're creating the icon. See the following example:

```
const centeredMarker = new H.map.Marker(
      {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude,
      },
      {
        icon: new H.map.Icon(imageElement, {
          anchor: new H.math.Point(markerWidth / 2, markerHeight / 2),
          crossOrigin: false,
        }),
      }
    );
```